# Nested settings with pydantic-settings

Tags: python-3.x, settings, pydantic, pydantic-settings

Using pydantic-settings (v2.0.3), I want to manage settings for services `service1` and `service2`, nesting them under the common `settings` object, so I can address them like `settings.service1.secret1` or `settings.service2.secret2`. Currently, I have this code in my `config.py`:

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings


class FirstServiceSettings(BaseSettings):
    secret1: str


class SecondServiceSettings(BaseSettings):
    secret2: str


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    service1: FirstServiceSettings
    service2: SecondServiceSettings

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"


settings = Settings()
```

And this is my `.env` file:

```
secret1=secret1
secret2=secret2
```

However, I'm getting `pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for Settings`.

The problem can be solved by adding `service1__` and `service2__` prefixes to keys in `.env` file and setting `env_nested_delimiter = '__'`, but I wonder is there a way to make this without adding those prefixes in `.env` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved using `BaseModel` and set `extra='ignore'` to `BaseSettings`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic_settings import VERSION, BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict

print(f'{VERSION = }')
# > VERSION = '2.0.3'


class BaseServiceSettings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file='.env', extra='ignore')


class FirstServiceSettings(BaseServiceSettings):
    secret1: str


class SecondServiceSettings(BaseServiceSettings):
    secret2: str


class Settings2(BaseModel):
    service1: FirstServiceSettings = FirstServiceSettings()
    service2: SecondServiceSettings = SecondServiceSettings()


settings = Settings2()
print(settings.model_dump_json())
# > {"service1":{"secret1":"secret1"},"service2":{"secret2":"secret2"}}
```

Comment: You are a saint. This answer saved my life after hours of head-banging with pydantic's V2 new way of doing things. Their official documentation is PLAIN WRONG! Thank you